# fckeditor occurred

Tags: php, html, fckeditor

I got an error while open the file of default.html of fckeditor.

Error is this

> Please open the about:config page and disable the  "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy" option; then load this page again.

Comment: did you do what the error said?

Comment: Obvious question: have you tried opening the about:config page and disabling the "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy" option? This is a Firefox setting. That would suggest that you're running fckeditor locally, without using a server. Any particular reason why you're doing this?

Comment: i am trying to remove this error beacuse with this error fckeditor files are not running on my browser. I am using google chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You should put "about:config" on the browser (where you put the URL's) and then change the value of security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy (from the list of variables) to disabled.

Comment: I have entered abou:config in the browser but it is saying that web page is not available (I am using google chrome)

Comment: You should use Firefox for use about:config. In chrome you should load chrome with the "--allow-file-access-from-files" command line flag set. More info: http://wiki.fluidproject.org/display/fluid/Browser+settings+to+support+local+Ajax+calls